# How to set Oracle encoding in Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

In Oracle you can set the encoding before saving some data into the DB by using `NLS_LANG=<the character set value>`

Is there a way to achieve this in Java so that when I'm saving data into the Oracle db,it uses a specific oracle character set value?

The reason I'm asking this is because my understanding is that this is achieved on a session level, which means that if that session is used by someone else, it will have the modified encoding.

What I would like to achieve programmatically in java is the following
Retrieve the current encoding
set the new encoding on the session
save data into the db
restore the old encoding on the session
release
Thank you

ps: I'm having difficulty setting the character set in Java, the specific type I need before writing to oracle is AL32UTF8
However, I can't seem to find a way to set this within the java app before data is saved

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643

Comment: A "session" is always dedicated to a user, i.e. a session cannot be used by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC applications do *not* use NLS_LANG (this is an exception to the rule).

[Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/setting-language-preferences-for-client-connections.html#GUID-78A71337-2199-4FED-B0F1-D313F769B22C) says:

> Java applications that connect to Oracle Databases by using Oracle
>   JDBC do not use NLS_LANG. Instead, Oracle JDBC maps the default locale
>   of the Java VM in which the application runs to the Oracle Database
>   language and territory settings. Oracle JDBC then configures the
>   connected database session using these settings. Because Java works
>   internally in Unicode, the client character set is always set to
>   Unicode. Unless an application explicitly changes it, the default
>   locale of the Java VM is set based on the locale of the user operating
>   system on which the Java VM runs. Check your Java VM documentation for
>   information about configuring the Java VM default locale.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to set this encoding AL32UTF8 within the java application. any advice?

Answer (score -1):

In case you run your Java program on the machine running your Oracle DB, you can set the  `NLS_LANG` environment variable and Oracle will use it